# How to display/embed Microsoft word Document(docx) in web page?

Tags: iframe, google-api, embed, docx

I am developer. i am developing a web application, in which, i need to display/embed docx file in div/web page part.

I have tried google api with using iframe code but not working like -

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://example.com/my.docx&embedded=true" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

but my application can not access by outside of my company. so this is not public documents. we can not upload the documents on google server.

So i am very confuse about the case ago a lot of time.

**Can we dispaly docx file into web page ?**

Please give a suggestion to resolve this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Please response anybody

Answer (score 0):

As of just now, you can try https://nativedocuments.com/

Native Documents has a component you can embed to view or edit Word (doc/docx) files in a web app.  You can host it, so your documents aren't transmitted over the public internet.

It is commercial software, but there are free tiers which may be enough for you.

**Disclosure: I have an interest in Native Documents.**